# GCP SSL on Cloud Storage with custom CNAME

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've set up a Cloud storage bucket for hosting images on my website, using a name to make it work with a subdomain of my app.

After a bit of searching I'm still unsure what is the best practice for getting it to work with HTTPS? I've seen that it might be setting up a Cloud Load Balancer?

Answer (score 0):

To add a Cloud Storage bucket to content-based load balancing see the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing) and this procedure assume you already Create a [Content-Based Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/content-based-example).